# If you and your angel both end up with the stone status do you get kicked out of the dungeon?

Tags: the-guided-fate-paradox

Lilliel is stoned and I am 1 turn away. I want to know if we both end up stoned if it is only temporary like paralyze or if we both 'die' and therefore you lose everything and are kicked out of the dungeon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, just like paralyzation, all status effects are temporary.  It will wear off in a few turns.  Do keep in mind, though, that if you're both stoned or slept, you're completely helpless and at the mercy of any aberrations that take a fancy to you.

Comment: This is mildly disappointing since I was doing well and left just in case and I don't think I have ever played a JRPG where Stone was not deadly but this is good to know now.